# Adding and Deleting from objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am pretty sure I have this right, but trying to add and delete using two separate method in my javascript code.

The first one, is specifically trying to add `classStr` to the HTML element object `el`,  property of `className`. If it already contains `classStr`, then it is left alone.

```
var addClass = function addClass(el, classStr) {
    if(el.className !== classStr) {
        el.className = classStr;
    }
};
```

This one, I am trying to simply delete `classStr` from `className` without leaving any white spaces. `el` is an element object. The only thing I am unsure about, is if I am leaving white spaces.

```
var removeClasfunction = function removeClass(el, classStr) {
    delete el.className;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The main disadvantage of your functions are that they don't handle multiple class names on the object.  In addition, you don't really want to be removing the property name, just setting it to an empty string when there are no class names.

Here's a set of utility functions for managing class names that works when there is more than one class name on an object which is something you should plan for (which yours do not).  These don't accumulate any extra whitespace:

```
function addClass(elem, cls) {
    if (!hasClass(elem, cls)) {
        var oldCls = elem.className;
        if (oldCls) {
            oldCls += " ";
        }
        elem.className = oldCls + cls;
    }
}

function removeClass(elem, cls) {
    var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    elem.className = str.replace(" " + cls + " ", " ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}

function hasClass(elem, cls) {
    var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    var testCls = " " + cls + " ";
    return(str.indexOf(testCls) !== -1) ;
}

function toggleClass(elem, cls) {
    if (hasClass(elem, cls)) {
        removeClass(elem, cls);
    } else {
        addClass(elem, cls);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not really understanding why you are putting in all of those extra white spaces when assigning assigning the variables.

Comment: @TheCrownedPixel - It's so that you force a whole word match so you never match the middle of a different class name.  It's a technique borrowed from how jQuery does it.  It could also be done with a regular expression (to only match word boundaries), but regular expressions are often times slower to execute and this is pretty simple.